# Middleman deploy error on build

Tags: github, deployment, build, middleman

When I try to run middleman deploy I get:

```
error  build/stylesheets/pages/about.css 
Undefined variable: "$gray-darker"
```

And I get this error on all my Pages about.css.scss, team.css.scss etc,...

I don't know if it is a problem with the compiler from scss to css ? 
When I run middleman on the local server the variables are fine, all the stylesheets work great. Anyone had the same issue while trying to deploy with middleman ?

Comment: I ended up by solving it found this answer after 3 days of search, I needed to add underscore in front of all my less files wich I was missing on some of my pages.scss. Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16095388/why-does-middleman-serve-work-but-middleman-build-fails-to-compile-this-sas